# jQuery Form Problem

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have developed a form using jQuery, HTML and a C# and ASPX back-end.

It works fine on Firefox and other Web browsers but if fails on Internet Explorer and don't know why.

I have tryied everything.

The URL is [Web Form](http://incolmotos.datacenter.arkix.com/appYamaha/Frmcontacto.aspx)

Any ideas??

Thanks!!

Comment: How is it failing? It seems to work on ie8.

Comment: What fails its the submit of the form that is made using an AJAX pettition via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The button is an `input type="button"`. Perhaps it should be `input type="submit"`? Don't know if IE has problems with type=button

Comment: What I did was to dinamically and the onClick attribute to the button after all the fields are validated :S all works fine but when all fields are validated and the AJAX function that sends all the data to the server is sents nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the entire problem, but I don't think you should use a body onload method. Use the built in jQuery option that is more cross browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // onload logic here
});
```